# is there a way to run QML Viewer for desktop that will show Qt Quick components on Meego Hamattan?

Tags: qt, qml, meego, meego-harmattan

I tried to run a Meego Hamattan Qt Quick project with Qt Quick components for Meego Hamattan that targets my desktop(Windows) and it only appears as all white.

I would like to be able to run Meego Hamattan UI in desktop, so that I wouldn't need to use QEmu(which is sluggish) to test my UI.

Please Answer my burning question! =)

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume your only choice is QEMU or a real device.
The QML meego components use platform code that is not available/compiled on your desktop.

Comment: But was reading Kate Alhola's Blog, [link](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Blogs/blog/kate-alholas-forum-nokia-blog/2011/06/23/nokia-meego-1.2-harmattan-qt-quick-components) the 1st image there shows that target device(Below Help, sorry don't know the proper name) is a monitor(desktop), And the QML Viewer is not a phone. hmm hmm.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is not with the components.. Is there are some errors in the QML code, the screen would be blank.. Look at the space below the workspace where compilation errors, build errors and application output will be notified.. If you note some text in Red color then its your mistake.. I can test my Qt quick and QML projects in Desktop build, Simulator build and also using QML viewer.. So the problem will not be the one you are mentioning..

Comment: are you using Qt Quick Components for Meego?
when targeting desktop Compile output:
Running build steps for project test2...
Configuration unchanged, skipping qmake step.
Starting: "C:\QtSDK\mingw\bin\mingw32-make.exe" 
C:/QtSDK/mingw/bin/mingw32-make -f Makefile.Debug
mingw32-make[1]: Entering directory `C:/Users/bcue/Qt/test2-build-desktop'
mingw32-make[1]: Nothing to be done for `first'.
mingw32-make[1]: Leaving directory `C:/Users/bcue/Qt/test2-build-desktop'
The process "C:\QtSDK\mingw\bin\mingw32-make.exe" exited normally.

Comment: Why not try it in Qt Simulator?